# Managed struct to/from pointer without boxing?

Tags: c#, pointers, struct

Let's say I have a struct that's not one of the C# primitives.

I'd like to know if there's a way (including unsafe code) to get a pointer from an instance of the struct type (the pointer doesn't have to be type-safe, it could be `void*`) and get an instance of the struct type from a pointer, but without boxing involved.

(I know that the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal` class offers almost what I'm describing, but it involves passing and getting structs as `object`, which means that boxing is involved.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite understand what is the problem with taking the address of the struct with `&` operator. If you're not aware of that, there exist [address of operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664779%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

For example:

```
struct Demo
{
    public int SomeField;
}

internal static class Program
{
    static Demo demo = new Demo { SomeField = 5 };

    private static void Main()
    {
        Print();
    }

    public static unsafe void Print()
    {
        fixed (Demo* demop = &demo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(demop->SomeField);
        }
    }
}
```

This code doesn't boxes the struct, though it needs *unsafe context* to compile.

Comment: Oh, this is very embarassing - I had tried doing this in a generic method using a `T : struct` and it failed with a "cannot take address of a managed type" error (while it worked on `int`, etc). So I (quite wrongly) assumed the problem was the type, not the fact that I was using generics. Considering this, my actual question should have been different, but since it is what it is, you are both correct of course.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an `unsafe` region to get the pointer using the `&` operator and convert back to the type using the `*` operator.

```
public struct Foo
{
    public int bar;
};

void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    foo.bar = 5;

    unsafe
    {
        Foo * fooPtr = &foo;
        Console.WriteLine("Foo address {0:X}", *fooPtr);

        Foo anotherFoo = *fooPtr;
        Console.WriteLine("Bar= {0}", anotherFoo.bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess 5 is the lucky number. We both use the same :p

Comment: I was just thinking that :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, why 5? Everyone knows that the answer is 42 ;)